# 1004 error on .Range.Select

Tags: vba, excel

How do I qualify the below worksheet/range to make the code not return

> 1004 Select method of Range class failed

on the last line?

```
Sub MarketsBudgetOverviewPDF()

Dim wb1 as Workbook
Dim MarketsBudgetPDFTemplate As Worksheet
Dim TemplateHeader As Range

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set MarketsBudgetPDFTemplate = wb1.Worksheets("Markets budget overview PDF")
Set TemplateHeader = MarketsBudgetPDFTemplate.Range("A1")

TemplateHeader.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
Sub MarketsBudgetOverviewPDF()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim MarketsBudgetPDFTemplate As Worksheet
Dim TemplateHeader As Range
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set MarketsBudgetPDFTemplate = wb1.Worksheets("Markets budget overview PDF")
Set TemplateHeader = MarketsBudgetPDFTemplate.Range("A1")

    MarketsBudgetPDFTemplate.Select
    'select the sheet above before selecting the Range below
    TemplateHeader.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pre-selecting the sheet, you could use `Goto`, which has the result of activating the sheet if necessary and then selecting the range/cell..

```
Application.Goto TemplateHeader
```